# Want to get folder id just by using os folder name in python but folder is empty?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a folder saved on my google drive which name is demo and i want to get the folder id of this folder just by using its folder name . I found some solutions on stackoverflow and other site but these are not understandable as i want to do it python. The folder is empty .

```
def findFolderId(folderName):
       pass
```

Comment: Are you trying to get folder path of specific folder name?

Comment: @WakemeUpNow I have no idea can i get path of folder first and then find folder id by its path in google drive api I want to find a folder id by name in python using google drive api so i can upload  file in that particular folder. Inititally the folder maybe empty. There is a possibility that folder can be empty or the folder has many files but only thing i have is folder name and google drive api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the file.list method and use the q parameter. to search for mime type of folder and the name of your folder name.

something like this should do it.

```
search = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = 'Test'"
fields = 'files(id, name, mimeType)'
results = drive_service.files().list(
        q=search ,
        fields=fields).execute()

items = results.get('files', [])
for item in items:
    print(u'{0} ({1})- {2}'.format(item['name'], item['id'], 
    item['mimeType']))
```

Comment: what i have to place instead of next_page_token can you tell me i am new to google drive api?

Comment: Sorry just remove that you dont need it for this call.